# how to use CSS child-nth when different type of child is present

Tags: css, css-selectors, children

I've got X div with a "block" class in my page, I want to manipulate div multiple of 2 (the even). But inside my page I've got an other DIV with a "not_block" class.

If I used:

```
.block:nth-child(even) {
    color:red;
}
```

It's working for the firsts divs until the bad div is parse...

Here's a  plknr to illustrate my problem:

https://plnkr.co/edit/axnb271p9aZIsEEv6GoL?p=preview

If you have any idea...

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're wanting to happen? `nth-child` is working as expected

Comment: if you've 7 childs, 3 blondes, 3 brunettes and the littlest one, redhead, when your wife tells you to change diapers to the littlest one, you'll ask for the hair colour? No. The CSS works as you with 7 childs. It's all ok